# Why does this OpenCV threshold call return a blank image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, graphics, opencv3.0

I am following this tutorial on OpenCV, where the tutorial uses the following code:

```
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True, help="path to input image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 255, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
cv2.imshow("Thresh", thresh)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Yet the image `thresh` displays as a blank window with a light grey background, where the tutorial is supposed to shoe a monochrome profile of an image that came with the tutorial source code.

I'm using the same code, and the same input image, yet the tutorial tells me to expect a monochrome image showing object outlines, while I only get a blank, grey image. What could be wrong here?

Comment: thresholding with min = 255 and max = 255 is a bit strange .... just check your gray image gray values to decide the right threshold value. (you can also post your image as well)

Comment: If you do not have any idea what threshold to use (lower value), start at mid-point, 128. Then adjust as needed. Or try the automatic Otsu thresholding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `thresh` parameter value should be different than `maxval` value.

```
thresh = cv2.threshold(src=gray,
                       thresh=127,
                       maxval=255,
                       type=cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gae8a4a146d1ca78c626a53577199e9c57)

- `gray` is your source image.
- `thresh` is the threshold value
- `maxval` is maximum value
- `type`is thresholding type

When you set both `thresh` and `maxval` the same value, you are saying:

> I want to display my pixels above 255 values, but none of the pixels should exceed 255.

Therefore the result is a blank image.

One possible way is setting thresh to 127.

For instance:

Original Image                                                     Thresholded Image

[image] [image]

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("fgtc7_256_256.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(src=gray,
                       thresh=127,
                       maxval=255,
                       type=cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
cv2.imshow("Thresh", thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```